# Using Experimental`OptimizeExpression for expression optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, output-formatting, formatting

I am trying to optimize the following expression (example only)

```
expr = Normal[Series[(1 - y - 2 z)^-2, {z, 0, 3}]]
```

whose output becomes

```
1/(1 - y)^2 - (4 z)/(-1 + y)^3 + (12 z^2)/(-1 + y)^4 - (32 z^3)/(-1 + y)^5
```

When using

```
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[expr]
```

I get

```
Experimental`OptimizedExpression[Block[{Compile`$98},
 Compile`$98 = -1 + y; 
 1/(1 - y)^2 - (4 z)/Compile`$98^3 + (12 z^2)/Compile`$98^4 - (32 z^3)/Compile`$98^5]]
```

where ``` Compile``$98 ``` changes everytime I compile. Is there any way to replace these `Compile**`?

The reason is I finally want to export this to C/Fortran where this symbol is problematic.

EDIT::
After some googling, I found that it is possible to rename the `Compile**` as

```
 Experimental`OptimizeExpression[expr, OptimizationSymbol -> a]
```

which produces

```
Experimental`OptimizedExpression[Block[{a71}, a71 = -1 + y; 
 1/(1 - y)^2 - (4 z)/a71^3 + (12 z^2)/a71^4 - (32 z^3)/a71^5]]
```

END EDIT

Another question: it says `Experimental`, so it is not yet completely verified functionality?